# Bootstrap 3 , different height columns layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently started using bootstrap 3 and I'm really loving the grid system.
I am however stuck trying to implement the following layout.

[image: Layout]

Is it possible to create something like  that with bootstrap?
I have read on the documentation about Column wrapping, is that the way to go?
**What would be the best approach to achieve it?**

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you running?

Comment: Bootstrap 3, thank you for asking... I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

What people often forget when using bootstrap is that it is fully customisable. You can use your own css to size and position divs as long as your css code goes after bootstrap.

Here is something similar to what you are trying to achieve: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cr840k7/)

```
<div id="wrapper" class="">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how the fiddle is similar to what I am looking for. Anyway thank you for your tips

Comment: You got two div. Fit another two divs in the left div and there is what you need..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it only with bootstrap.
You should probably use https://github.com/desandro/masonry that solves this exact problem.

Bootstrap uses float to position your columns, while Masonry compute absolute position to put the div on the right place.

You can still use Bootstrap for defining responsive behaviour of your column (the width propriety)